# Data from multiple tables based on common id

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Everything I need is on this web page: https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2019.html

I would like to write something that steps through the names in the Roster table, then searches other specific tables in the page (totals for example) for that player name, adding the new data to the end of the row for that player name.

Here's what I've got so far, just the code to get the roster info..any direction or tips would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import calendar
import pandas as pd
import os


season = str(date.today().year )
month = calendar.month_name[date.today().month].lower()
teamUrl = "https://basketball-reference.com/teams/"

teamRoster =    {'BOS': teamUrl + 'BOS/' + season +'.html'} 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for url in teamRoster.values():
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    #teamName = soup.find(class_="teams*").find_all('span')[1]
    for i in soup.find_all('table', id='roster'):
        for row1 in i.select('tr')[1:]:
            listA = ([td.text for td in row1.select("td")])
            print(listA)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the output format you want as you will end up with a lot of columns?

Comment: Yes that is the output I'm after